# Node SerialPort on Linux CentOS 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, centos6, node-serialport

I am new to node js. I have created an app using node, express, socket and serialport. I have a weighing scale connected to serialport (COM2). On windows (localhost) it is perfectly working. But when I deployed it on my Linux CentOS 6 server it is not reading any serialport.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "socket",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "wieghing machine serial port socket app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0",
    "bindings": "1.2.1",
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "debug": "^2.4.5",
    "nan": "^2.4.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.6.32"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serialport": "^4.0.7"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var SerialPort = require('serialport');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('register', function(msg){
    io.emit('register', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(8081, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8081');
});


var port = new SerialPort("COM2", {
  baudrate: 9600
});

port.on('data', function (data) {
    io.emit('WeightMachine', data.toString());
});

SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.comName);
    console.log(port.pnpId);
    console.log(port.manufacturer);
  });
});
```

Please do not mark my question negative I really am new to node js.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change http.listen(8081) to http.listen(8081."0.0.0.0",fun...)

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with NodeJS. Are you able to read from that COM port using native CentOS tools?

Comment: it is showing error http.listen(8081."0.0.0.0", function(){ unexpected string

Comment: COM2 is not a valid name on linux, should be something like '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Comment: @JohnSmith I just tested it over widows and it worked fine. I do not know why it is not working on linux CentOS

Comment: Windows is not CentOS. It's a totally different world. I asked you to test it using native CentOS tools because I expect the system can not read the device because it's ill configured.

Comment: @ErikMan I have tried /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyUSB1 but unfortunately it is not working

Comment: @JohnSmith I have not tested it over any CentOS tool. I am not fimiliar with this. Thanks. Let me try it.

Comment: @JohnSmith can you please provide me any name or link of native CentOS tool. I am not fimiliar with this.

Answer (score 0):

By default your code runs on localhost when not supplied the 2nd params, but when running on server it needs to be changed as. Also make sure that 8081 port is enabled on server

```
 http.listen(8081,"0.0.0.0", function(){
   console.log('listening on *:8081');
 });
```